# using struts2.2.1 annotations with netbeans 6.9 not working

Tags: struts2, annotations, netbeans-6.9

Hello Im doing the convention  [plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/convention-plugin.html) for struts2.2.1, examples with netbeans6.9
and it seems like something is wrong. I even copy/paste everything and nothing. rightnow I get :

"The error message is ${message}  "
    when it should be

"The error message is Hello World"

i could not post the structure, but I put the jsp under the WEB-INF following the tutorial
but nothing

web.xml

```
<web-app>
<display-name>My Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello-world.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

myaction:

```
package com.example.actions;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
  private String message;

  public String getMessage() {
   return message;
  }

  public String execute() {
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
       message = "It's 0";
       return "zero";
   }

    message = "It's 1";
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

hello-world.jsp

```
<html>
<body> 
The Error message is ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

I don´t think I need a strut.xml file. I´m really getting frustrated here 
would really appreciate any help or can´t you do annotations with struts2.2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your welcome-file in web.xml it would only display "The Error message is".

You need to go straight to the action, so that you get an initial value. You need an additional index.html like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dummy Project</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=hello.action">
</head>

<body>
<p>Project is Loading ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.html should be your welcome-file in your web.xml. Your struts.xml is here:

```
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
   <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
    <package name="foo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="hello" class="com.example.action.HelloWorld">
            <result name="success">/hello-world.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

"hello" is your action. Only a "success" result is necessary here. After the action runs, you will be redirected to your hello-world.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        The Error message is ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is your HelloWorld.java. Execute() returns only SUCCESS. This should be sufficient.

```
package com.example.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0)
            message = "It's 0";
        else 
            message = "It's 1";
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

You can certainly do the same with annotations. It should be easy to make this work.
I use this [NetBeans Struts2 Support](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=23467) plugin. Enjoy...

Costis